# complexType in schema

Tags: xml, xsd

In my xml I have a price tag and I want to make a restriction in the amount of decimal digits and the kind of currency, I have this:

```
  `<unit_price currency="$"> 4.00 </unit_price>`
```

In the xsd I´m getting this error:

**E [Xerces] cos-applicable-facets: Facet 'fractionDigits' is not allowed by type #AnonType_Price.**

This my code, pl how can I fix it? Thnks.

```
<xsd:complexType name="basePrice">
    <xsd:simpleContent>
        <xsd:extension base="xsd:double">
            <xsd:attribute name="currency" fixed="$"/>
        </xsd:extension>
    </xsd:simpleContent>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="Price">
    <xsd:simpleContent>
        <xsd:restriction base="basePrice">
            *<xsd:fractionDigits value="2"/>*   
        </xsd:restriction >
    </xsd:simpleContent>
</xsd:complexType>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't restrict the number of fractional digits in a double, only in a decimal. This is because counting digits is only a meaningful operation when numbers are expressed in decimal notation.